# How data flows to executor in spark job processing

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark on top of hadoop cluster .Hadoop has data blocks on which we need to run spark job. My query is what if the partition is in node2 and executor is in node3. How executor in node3 will process data block of node2. Do the data in the partition in node2 is transferred to node3 .
How internally the spark makes sure executor has partition in the same machine to process?

Answer (score 1):

Any HDFS Client can read remote data blocks. They don't need to be "node local" lookups; that's just an optimization that YARN tries to accomplish.

In the Spark UI, you should be able to see what tasks from the execution timeline are local or remote